Why 8051 is not detecting logic from circuit's voltage?
I am working on a ASK modulator and demodulator circuit which I wish to interface with a 8051 microcontroller to read serial data from demodulator circuit. The mod/demod circuit is developed and without connection to 8051 produces approx. 4V for logic HIGH and -0.05V for logic LOW. But upon connecting it to 8051 port3 pin2, the voltage at the pins doesn't change but stays at approx. 5V. What could I be doing wrong in designing the mod/demod circuit?

What do the little red squares mean?

The little red square on the left side mean that the pin is currently at logic high.

The common 8051 has (weak) pull-up "resistors" on most of its pins. This is the primitive way to save logic and registers to set the direction of the pin.
Look up in the data sheet for your specific MCU about the characteristics. Actually these pull-ups are implemented as current sources in many MCUs.
The pull-up at P3.2 loads C2 on the left side to approximately 5V.
One possible solution is to add another comparator or CMOS Schmitt-Trigger gate between the 741 and the 8051.
